# Azure logins (login.microsoftonline.com) ask me to authenticate in every new browser tab on Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome, microsoft

I have an issue where on my Mac, every single time I open a new Chrome/Safari window, I am being asked to re-authenticate to access Microsoft Azure. Even though I have selected the "remember me" option. I have confirmed that it is not conditional access on the Azure side causing it, definitely something local.

Does anyone have any suggestions please?